# Unset "use all monitors for the remote session" in hyper-v

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, hyper-v

i clicked the setting "use all monitors for the remote session" while starting the rdp-session via hyper-v (extended). Where can i unset this option. I found nothing. Any regedit entry?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. You can unset this by right clicking the appropriate entry in virtual computers and choose "Edit Session Settings".

https://github.com/microsoft/linux-vm-tools/issues/34 (first Screenshot)

**IMPORTANT:** You must close the rdp-session window of this VM otherwise it will only focus this window instead of showing the options.

Answer (score 0):

Find the the RDP file of the connection (`*.rdp`) and edit the
following line:

```
Use Multimon:i:1
```

Change the line to :

```
use multimon:i:0
```

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me. I have no specific rdp-file. I use the connection method shipped by hyper-v itself. This automatically starts a rdp session. I don't know where this *.dpf files are stored.
Nevertheless i found a solution. I will explain this in a new answer.